# OpenSSL handshake logic in code

Tags: ssl, openssl

The code for SSL_do_handshake can be found at [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl)/ssl/ssl_lib.c.
The SSL_do_handshake function will wait for a TLS handshake to take place.
I am not able to understand the logic for the implementation. If my understanding is correct, the [TLS handshake](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660_.htm) consists of a few steps before a symmetric key is generated. Where can I find the various steps in code (sending client hello, etc) for the implementation of the SSL_do_handshake() function. Are these steps in different parts of the OpenSSL library. If so, how are they tracked/called in the do_handshake function ?

Broader context:
Software like apache/nginx uses OpenSSL in their code. I would like to replace the SSL_do_handshake() function used in the apache/nginx code with a modified handshake. For this I need to understand the logic for the implementation in OpenSSL. Note, that I am looking to replace the API call with my modified API call. I do not want to make changes to openssl and then recompile and use the modified OpenSSL library. The modified_handshake API should be able to replace the symmetric key generated at the end of the handshake with a user generated key.

Comment: The TLS state machine is complex as is the implementation in OpenSSL. With the latest openssl 1.1.0 they have reworked the implementation. Have a look at ssl/statem which also contains a small README. Apart from that, dig through the code, starting with what you know (`do_handshake`) and fill in what you'll find on the way. There is no design documentation for this as far as I know, just the code.

Comment: The TLS/SSL full handshake produces one master secret (which is not a key) and 2 to 6 derived key values. Which do you want to replace, and how will you communicate with anyone after doing so? Also remember renegotiation handshake can be initiated by the peer at any time with no local API call and generates new derived keys even if it reuses a session and master secret.